# How to match information between tabs?

Tags: google-sheets

How can I take information from one tab and add it to another?

For example, I have Tab 1 with column A - call it `cat breeds` - and I have Tab 2 with column A - call it `cat breeds` as well. They need to match so if these two match I need Tab 2 column B with `cat names` to show in Tab 1 on the same row that matches the `cat breeds` in a new column.

Answer (score 1):

I'll have a guess that:

```
=vlookup(A2,Tab2!A:B,2,0)
```

in Tab1 B1 and copied down might suit.